# Using the MERGE statement to merge large amounts of data on Windows Azure SQL Database causing error 40552

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I'm currently merging large data sets in *Windows Azure SQL Database*. I was wondering if there was a way not to get the following error:

> 40552 : The session has been terminated because of excessive transaction log space usage. Try modifying fewer rows in a single transaction.

My data sets are larger than 15 million records.

Comment: Can you not process all data in 1 transaction?

Comment: No SQL Database on Windows Azure protects itself  very agressively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an application find the number of record that need to be imported and based on the batch size calculate the number of batches that need to be executed. Then for each batch, create a new SQL Command which executes the merge Stored Procedure with the right offset Index. Be sure to insert a short delay between each SQL Command, because if they run too fast Windows Azure SQL Database might raise a **40501** due to an excessive number of requests.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MergeCustomerTables]
        @offsetIndex int = 0,
        @batchSize int = 10000
AS

DECLARE @offset as bigint

SELECT @offset = @offsetIndex *  @batchSize

MERGE Customers AS Target
USING (SELECT a.[Name], a.[LastName], a.[Email] from CustomerInsertTable as a
       ORDER BY a.[Email]
       OFFSET  @offset ROWS 
       FETCH NEXT @batchSize ROWS ONLY 
) AS Source
ON (Target.[Email] = Source.[Email])
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.[Name] = Source.[Name]
             , Target.[LastName] = Source.[LastName]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ([Name], [LastName], [Email])
    VALUES (
     Source.[Name] 
     , Source.[LastName]
     , Source.[Email]
    );
```